# Avoiding XML escaped values (e.g. &gt;) in TransformerFactory

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb, marshalling

I am writing the xml document into a file, using TransformerFactory. XML document has characters like '>', but while marshalling it back instead of ">" its printing "&gt ;"
  For marshall and unmarshall I am using JAXB-Binder.

```
private void writeIntoFile( Document document, File xmlPath ){
    document.createProcessingInstruction( StreamResult.PI_DISABLE_OUTPUT_ESCAPING, "");

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    try{
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        t.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml" );
        t.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        t.transform( new DOMSource( document ), new StreamResult( System.out ) );
    }
    catch( TransformerException e ){
        logger.error( e, "Exception while marshalling the document in the xml file [", xmlPath.getAbsolutePath() );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is part of the XML spec.